# Copied site to localhost, but URL base is not correct for links or images

Tags: php, wordpress

I just pulled a copy from a live site and installed locally using XAMPP. The directory is:

`127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename`

The homepage pulls up just fine, but no images load. The links do not work either. Image and link URLs have not updated to reflect the new directory. They still show as:

`/categoryname/pagename`

Instead of

`/website-files/websitename/categoryname/pagename`

The site is wordpress, and the general settings are updated:

Wordpress Address `http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename`

Site Address `http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename`

I added this to functions.php, which I assumed would do all the changes I needed:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename');
update_option('home','http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename');
```

`.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website-files/websitename/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /website-files/websitename/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I run into an issue every time I move a website to a new dev server, but this one is a first. What am I missing here?

Comment: I was getting the same problem with Wordpress, so I started using `hosts` file (on Windows) to point domain name to localhost. You can try this if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a leading `/` for any links for your website, so instead of:

```
 <a href="/foo">foo</a>
 <img src="/images/bar.jpg">
```

Do this:

```
 <a href="foo">foo</a>
 <img src="images/bar.jpg">
```

And finally, you might want to experiment with adding a "base href" tag to the top of your HTML, which would have a different value depending on what server you're running on. A quick google for base href will teach you how this works.

You might have to restructure how you build webpages to make this happen. That's simply how things are if you want to be able to run a single website on more than one server.

If you're using Wordpress or another similar open source framework, you might be screwed. Some of them are simply incapable of operating on more than one server.

Comment: I have setup this same website on multiple servers, it is just infrequent enough that I forget the exact steps. This one seems to be a base url issue. It should be just like moving WP into a new directory, but for some reason it is not recognizing the new URL.

Comment: @Eric I can't really give you any help with htaccess, because in my experience the correct values are different from one server to another. What works for me probably won't work for you. Probably try messing with leading/trailing slashes to start with... but in general I've learned to try to avoid using htaccess as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to confirm that `home` and `siteurl` have been updated in your local database's `wp_options` table.

Alternately you can can try setting `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to point to your local files in `wp-config.php`. This overrides the settings in the options table.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename');
```

Comment: I actually deleted everything and started from scratch, going straight to the database to make those changes the second time. Everything looks right: `http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename` is in the database, in the general settings, etc. I even added the code to `functions.php` just in case. This is just baffling. The links and media thinks everything is in `127.0.0.1` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/website-files/websitename`. Very frustrating indeed.

Comment: My guess is that themes and/or plugins that you have been using have hardcoded paths to these assets. Try doing a search and replace for this prefix in the dumped sql.